# Flutter Autocomplete: how to set selected option to null

Tags: flutter, select, autocomplete

Autocomplete always selects the first element in
drop-down list of found matches. how to make it so that no element in drop-down is selected. I want the user to select items manually (onTap).

[Here is an example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html#material.Autocomplete.1).
Typing an "a" will automatically select the first item in the dropdown. I don't want the first element to be selected (i.e. null or something similar)

I want, if the user enters an "a", a dropdown is displayed but no element is selected and no element is accepted when confirming with Enter.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Added `fieldViewBuilder` to prevent selection on enter.

To achieve that, you can use `optionsViewBuilder`, like this:

```
Autocomplete<String>(
  fieldViewBuilder:
      (context, textEditingController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      focusNode: focusNode,
    );
  },
  optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
    if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
      return const Iterable<String>.empty();
    }
    return _kOptions.where((String option) {
      return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
    });
  },
  optionsViewBuilder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
    Iterable<String> options,
  ) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemCount: options.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final String option = options.elementAt(index);
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  onSelected(option);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(option),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  onSelected: (String selection) {
    debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
  },
)
```

Now no option is preselected:
[image: No option is preselected]

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't quite work. the first element is still selected in the background. It's just not highlighted visually.

 If you type "a" and then confirm with enter, then Autocomplete takes preselected first element.

Comment: Ok, I missed that part. Then you should provide your own `fieldViewBuilder` which will not have `onFieldSubmitted` property (which the default `Autocomplete` has).

Comment: Thank you. It's already looking a lot better. But now the confirmation with Enter no longer works. I mean if you want to select the first element manually with keyboard arrows, you can no longer confirm it.
So it's a cool workaround, but its a workaround with small downsides.  :). But it's a maybe a step in the right direction for me